# Search a cell for a value that exists in a list to pull a value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a list of strings that within the cells contain the name of a State. I then have a list of the States and I want to have a formula that is able to search the string for a State name and then give me the name of the State.

I've used nested `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*Florida*")=1,"Florida"...)` in the past for similar exercises but I don't want to create a version for all 50 States. Is there a way to do this combining some kind of INDEX MATCH?

Image below is a snippet of the kind of data. For the most part, the State name follows the year but not always and the suffix isn't always Invitational so there's no way to use those two to book-end the part of the string that contains the State.

Any help would be appreciated!

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyo7d.png)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: In the adjacent column, the State name. e.g. In the first entry in the example, it would simply say Tennessee. Which it would get from searching against the State column

Comment: Is the rule to search for the first word on each row?

Comment: A match of cells against a fixed list of states?

Comment: With given example you could avoid listing the states and use `MID` to search for the text after the Year and removing the last word. Is all data structured that way? `=MID(A1,6,LEN(A1)-13-5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the filter function, here's a clean short formula. Assume Column E:E has your list of states, and then just reference the cell...

```
=Textjoin("",true,FILTER(if(isnumber(Search(E:E,A2)),E:E,),E:E<>""))
```

[image]

### Updated:

Stealing from JvDV this is probably a better version of what I tried to setup:

```
=FILTER(E:E,(isnumber(SEARCH(E:E,A2))*(E:E<>"")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something along these line:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTER(D$2:D$4,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&D$2:D$4&"*"))
```

Or:

```
=FILTER(D$2:D$4,ISNUMBER(FIND(D$2:D$4,A1)))
```

Comment: Oh... I'm not sure why I didn't do my filter the way you did your second answer. For some reason I got caught up in TextJoin... nice answer. I changed mine to use `Search` instead of `Find` as I can't imagine a state should not be identified if the capitalization was wrong (i.e. `South carolina`)

Comment: True @pgSystemTester, `SEARCH()` could possibly be a better alternative =)

Comment: When I tried the first option it worked for the first row but then all subsequent rows were 0. If I then do it in next column and start at the second row it works for that row again but then nothing further. It is something to do with the A1 value being fixed and not going to A2, A3 etc. for each subsequent row?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,
FIND("~", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-(FIND(" ",A1)+1)),
LEFT(A1,FIND("~", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))))
```

if you have office 365, and you don't want to use an extra helper column then this formula can be helpful

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1," ",2,0,1,"")," ",1,0,1,""),TEXTBEFORE(A1," ",1,0,1,"")),"")
```

Just Added New formula so you can avoid using a new helper column

**All** you have to do is, **"-"** in the state names with space. like New-York
As if you use New York, The result will only be **New**

[image: Required Result without Helper Column]

Comment: This would have problems if there were two spaces after the state. Example: `1976 Florida Masters Invitational`.